# PHP allowing invalid code in switch statements

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm having some trouble understanding why the following doesn't result in a compiler error in 5.3.3 (errored-out correctly on my coworkers 5.2.5):

```
<?php
    echo "starting\n";

    switch(1) {
        case 2:
            echo "two\n";
            break;
        defalut:        // note the misspelling
            echo "deflaut\n";
    }

    echo "ending\n";
```

Instead of giving me a compiler error (or even a warning) it just gives this:

```
starting
ending
```

However, if I use it in an if-statement it gives me what I'd expect:

```
<?php
    if (1 == deflaut)
        echo "deflaut2\n";
```

gives:

```
PHP Notice:  Use of undefined constant deflaut - assumed 'deflaut' in ...
```

Why is this? Is there a setting somewhere I can disable to tell it to be strict about this sort of thing?

Comment: Great question.  I'm inclined to think it's a bug in 5.3.3 but I'm interested to see what the answers are.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that so many people are reading the code but not the question :-P

Comment: @Ben: That's not the question.

Comment: The [changelog](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.1.0) for version 5.1.0 states (among other things): "Improved performance of...switch() statement." This doesn't answer "why" but may at least provide a "when."

Comment: @George Cummins as noted by the op, it errors correctly in 5.2.5 so whatever that change was in 5.1.0 probably doesn't apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your code isn't doing what you think.  A `case` block only ends when the next `case` block occurs, or when `default:` is found, or when the closing `}` is reached.  This means that `defalut` is part of the `case 2:` block.  So it is never even interpreted.

However, it doesn't even fire a syntax error (not even if you do `switch (2)`. This is because the [`goto`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) operator was introduced in PHP 5.3.  The syntax `word:` at the beginning of a PHP statement is now a target accessible via `goto`.  So `goto defalut;` can be used to go to the label.

<sub>(Actually, it can't, because of a restriction on targets inside `switch` blocks to avoid infinite loops, but this should illustrate the point...)</sub>

You can make it force an error by doing `case defalut`, when the error that you expect is found.

Comment: Great explanation that makes a lot of sense. +1 and thank you.

Comment: "This is because the goto operator was introduced in PHP 5.3."

ಠ_ಠ

Answer (score 8):

It could possibly be interpreting it as just another label (which makes sense, given that technically `default` *is* a label and `case` could be interpreted as a special kind of label too) that could be used with `goto`. Try a `goto` and find out. I would, but I don't have PHP 5.3.3, sorry.

Comment: This is correct. Similar issues exist in C/C++ http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/217909-faulty-default

Comment: Then why would it error in 5.2? Which version of PHP should be considered the one not handling it correctly? Or is this an intentional change?

Comment: @minitech Correct, it's a php 5.3 goto label. @Endophage In PHP 5.2 goto was not available, so it errors out.

Comment: Not saying you're wrong, but it gave me an error trying to goto it:  `PHP Fatal error:  'goto' into loop or switch statement is disallowed in...`

Comment: Well on the syntax level you can place the goto labels into various locations, but that does not mean that you actually can reach them with goto. That's resolved at runtime, but the syntax at compile time. So you've just defined a goto label it's forbidden to go to ;)

Comment: @fiXedd: The error shows clearly that's a goto label, because goto knows where it is and that it can't jump there. Just noting.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, on my 5.3.2, this does fail *IF* there is NO other case statement above the mispelled default.

This dies with a "T_UNEXPECTED_STRING" syntax error:

```
switch (1) {
   defalut:
       echo "this should never come out";
       break;
   default:
       echo "default matched properly"
}
```

This one works:

```
switch (1) {
   case 2:
        echo "2\n";
        break;
   defalut:
        echo "this should never come out";
        break;
   default:
        echo "the default value\n";
}
```

It would appear you've found a bug in the PHP parser. Wouldn't consider a serious bug, but a bug nonetheless.

Comment: This is because all code in a switch construct must appear within a `case` or `default`. You would receive an unexpected *anything* if it isn't inside a `case` or `default`. Your second example is a label within a `case` so it compiles.

Comment: Technically, the case should be considered closed by the break statement. But I guess if PHP's parse tree only closes on another case or an actual default, this'd make sense.